# Save method conflict when using Django Admin feature

Tags: django, django-admin

My model uses custom save method to add my own "primary key":

```
class Z(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(K, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    my_id = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        counter = Z.objects.filter(author=self.author).count() + 1
        self.my_id = str(counter) + "/" + self.author.name
        super(Z, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But when I'm trying to edit anything in Django Admin panel it still uses my save method- which causes a lot of problems (when I'm editing multiple items it gives it the same ID, etc). Is there any way that I can force Admin panel editing to not use my save method?

Comment: explain more, you are making a save method and you don't want the admin to use it ? :shock:

Comment: @Moha369 I want to use it when saving (I mean when creating new object) but not when editing already existing one. But when I edit anything it uses my save() function too thus causing all the turmoil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround- created custom function in admin panel that made what I wanted to made without saving anything.